# JavaFX FXML NullPointerException with Scenebuilder 2.0 & IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx-8, fxml, scenebuilder

I am having a problem with my JavaFX project.
I have created a FXML file and edited it with scenebuilder 2.0. I also created a controller-class for that specific FXML file, and set the correct fx:id's in scenebuilder. However, I am getting a `NullPointerException` on running the code:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.view.MenuLeftController.setUnitStatus(MenuLeftController.java:33)
    at application.view.Controller.handleShipClick(Controller.java:96)
    at application.view.Controller.lambda$drawShipOnMap$1(Controller.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.postProcess(Scene.java:3470)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ClickGenerator.access$8100(Scene.java:3398)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3766)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is the controller-class:

```
package application.view;

import application.MainApp;
import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class MenuLeftController {
    private MainApp mainApp;

    @FXML
    @NotNull
    private Label ship_name;
    @FXML
    private Label ship_status;
    @FXML
    private Label phys_status;
    @FXML
    private Label ship_speed;
    @FXML
    private Label ship_course;

    public void setMainApp(MainApp stuff) {
        mainApp = stuff;
    }

    //Default constructor
    public void MenuLeftController() {
        //nothing here...
    }

    public void setUnitStatus(String shipName, String shipStatus, int health, int totalHealth, int shipSpeed, int shipCourse) {
        ship_name.setText(shipName);
        ship_speed.setText(Integer.toString(shipSpeed));
        ship_course.setText(Integer.toString(shipCourse));
        ship_status.setText(shipStatus);

        if (health == totalHealth) {
            phys_status.setText("OK");
        } else if (health >= 0.75 * totalHealth && health < totalHealth) {
            phys_status.setText("Minor Damage");
        } else if (health >= 0.25 * totalHealth && health < 0.75 * totalHealth) {
            phys_status.setText("Damage");
        } else if (health > 0 && health < 0.25 * totalHealth) {
            phys_status.setText("Heavy Damage");
        } else {
            phys_status.setText("Sinking");
        }
    }

}
```

I recently switched from Eclipse with the E(fx)clipse plugin to IntelliJ community edition. This is the first FXML file I'm editing using IntelliJ, so maybe it has something to do with IntelliJ, since another FXML file + controller-class work perfectly, but those were made in Eclipse.

Let me know if I forgot to add something, thanks.

**EDIT:**
This is the piece of code in Controller.java where I call the setUnitStatus method in MenuLeftController:

```
MenuLeftController menuLeft = new MenuLeftController();
menuLeft.setUnitStatus(shipName, "Patrolling", shipHealth, totalHealth, speed, course);
```

Comment: Which line is that line 33?

Comment: Also show how the `setUnitStatus` is called from the other controller/how you get the controller instance there...

Comment: Never mind.. It seems like you didnt edit any lines out, so line 33 is first line of the method. Try opening the FXML file in IDE, sometimes IDE does not register a change made from SceneBuilder, which causes the application to use old file.

Comment: I already checked if the fx:id's were assigned in the actual fxml file, They were, So no problem there.

Comment: How do you get the `MenuLeftController` instance in your `Controller` class (The one used in the following lines of the stacktrace: `at application.view.Controller.handleShipClick(Controller.java:96)`)?

Comment: Thnks for the response, I added the piece of code to my question ;)

Comment: You are not supposed to manually instantiate a controller for a FXML. You should create a`FXMLLoader` and use that to load the FXML file, then get the controller from the loader.

Comment: Thanks, I diverted the method to the main class, so I didn't have to create a second controller and it did the trick. :)

Comment: You had this exception because you created a new instance of your controller.You should get your controller from your fxml file.